# Should the .babelrc file be gitignored?

Tags: node.js, git, babeljs, gitignore

I have a project that uses babel, and I was curious if a .babelrc file is typically gitignored or not. I am using a couple of presets that are apart of the package.json file that I have in the .babelrc file so it seems like a .babelrc file should be in source control, but not totally sure.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**tldr;** you should not ignore it.

In case you have some codebase which can be compiled only under relevant babel configuration, you need to specify appropriate configuration for babel. So it becomes obvious that everyone who will run this project from scratch will need to have that pre-defined to run an application properly.